# GoJs addDiagramListener SelectionMoved get data using SelectedNode

Tags: gojs

I am running the following code:

```
myDiagram.addDiagramListener("SelectionMoved", function (event) {

    console.log("SelectionMoved ...");
    // https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Part.html#location // * PART

    var selectedNode = event.diagram.selection.first();
    var key = selectedNode.key;
    var coorX =  selectedNode.location.x;
    var coorY =  selectedNode.location.y;
}
```

When I inspect the element  'selectedNode' I see object prop  'hb' which contains the data element. (see image below).

[image]

I would like to access some of the data-fields in the object like

*selectNode.hb.assignedTo*

How can I access these props when using var selectedNode = event.diagram.selection.first(); ?

**SOLUTION**
I was able to get the data element by using the following code:

```
myDiagram.addDiagramListener("SelectionMoved", function (event) {
    console.log("SelectionMoved ...");
    // https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Part.html#location // * PART

    var selectedNode = event.diagram.selection.first();
    var key = selectedNode.key;
    var coorX =  selectedNode.location.x;
    var coorY =  selectedNode.location.y;

    // ****** NODE DATA ********
    var nodeData = selectedNode.data;  //node data
    var assignedTo = nodeData.assignedTo;
    var diagramGuid = nodeData.diagramId,    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should never use minified property names.
https://gojs.net/latest/intro/index.html#DevelopingYourDiagram

Use the **Panel.data** property: `selectNode.data.assignedTo`
https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Panel.html#data